# It does not complete "flutter doctor running" loading at all.help me

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

It does not complete loading at all.
I've been waiting for over 10 minutes for "flutter doctor running" to complete in vscode,
but it never does.
I've done "flutter doctor" using windows powershell with administrator privileges and it completes with no problem.
Can anyone help me with a solution?

I tried the following, but "it" did not start.
"VScode on → Run:flutter doctor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open VScode with administrator privileges and then run flutter doctor